# Is it possible to include Google App Script (associated with spreadsheet) in JSP or call .gs function in a JSP

Tags: jsp, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Spreadsheet and HTML 5 to create different charts in my application. I'm using xmlhttp.responseXML and fetching spreadsheet and successfully able to display data.

**I want to know how can I call a function of code.gs in JSP.**

function can be the simple one. for ex.

```
 function getScriptUrl()
 {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
 }
```

My actual purpose is to Log some activites in a particular sheet in the same spreadsheet. If I'm able to call a function in code.gs, I could do it easily.
Any solution or better suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks,

Shahid

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly call the functions of the *gs.file

You can send and receive data through [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service)